# Object.any_instance should_receive vs expect() to receive

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

The following piece of code works as expected:

```
Object.any_instance.should_receive(:subscribe)
```

But when using the new rspec expectation it does not work:

```
expect(Object.any_instance).to receive(:subscribe)
```

The error is:

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

How can I make this work with expect() to receive?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

There's now a not very well documented method called `expect_any_instance_of` that handles the `any_instance` special case.  You should use:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:subscribe)
```

Google `expect_any_instance_of` for more info.

Comment: +1 for "not very well documented". Still the case. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods:expect_any_instance_of

Comment: I have been using `allow_any_instance_of`. Is it an alias of this method?

Comment: @rubyprince They're different, with the allow methods stubbing behaviour and expect methods testing for behaviour.

For example, `allow(my_obj).to receive(:method_name).and_return(true)` stubs `my_obj.method_name()` so if it's called in the test it simply returns `true`.

`expect(my_obj).to receive(:method_name).and_return(true)` doesn't change any behaviour, but sets up a test expectation to fail if `my_obj.method_name()` isn't called later in the test or doesn't return true.

Comment: Thanks @Saigo. Makes sense now.

Comment: This syntax is deprecated. Is there any hints on how to do this in today's syntax?

Comment: It is deprecated because it is not clear what you mean by `expect_any_instance_of ` (especially if you have to test several interactions on the same object VS different object), however I still find this very convenient. (source: some thread in the RSpec forums)

Comment: For the syntax deprecation, see [@Arreth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57962004/610351)

Comment: Syntax works fine without deprecation warnings for me

Answer (score 9):

Just a heads up, `expect_any_instance_of` is now considered deprecated behaviour according to [Jon Rowe (key rspec contributor)](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1187#issuecomment-345560439). The suggested alternative is to use the `instance_double` method to create a mock instance of your class and expect calls to that instance double, as described in that link.

Jon's method is preferred (since it can be used as a generalized test helper method). However if you find that confusing, hopefully this implementation for your example case can help make sense of the intended method:

```rb
mock_object = instance_double(Object) # create mock instance
allow(MyModule::MyClass).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_object) # always return this mock instance when constructor is invoked

expect(mock_object).to receive(:subscribe)
```

Good luck!